# Error: inflating class fragment & Performing stop of activity that is not resumed. Only on Upgrade app

Tags: android, fragment, runtime-error

Good morning everybody )
I published an app and it works well.
Now I make some implementations and I uploaded the new version of my app

When user installs the upgrade, i get a crash on start !
with: Error inflating class fragment

If I install the app as new install everything works well!

```
    Process: com.crifano.tatooPhoto, PID: 30129
java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{com.crifano.tatooPhoto/com.crifano.tatooPhoto.ui.MainActivity}: android.view.InflateException: Binary XML file line #78: Error inflating class fragment
        at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2328)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2386)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.access$900(ActivityThread.java:169)
        at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1277)
        at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102)
        at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:136)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5476)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:515)
        at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:1283)
        at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:1099)
        at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
 Caused by: android.view.InflateException: Binary XML file line #78: Error inflating class fragment
        at android.view.LayoutInflater.createViewFromTag(LayoutInflater.java:719)
        at android.view.LayoutInflater.rInflate(LayoutInflater.java:761)
        at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:498)
        at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:398)
        at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:354)
        at com.android.internal.policy.impl.PhoneWindow.setContentView(PhoneWindow.java:366)
        at android.app.Activity.setContentView(Activity.java:2031)
        at com.crifano.tatooPhoto.ui.MainActivity.onCreate(Unknown Source)
        at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:5451)
        at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1093)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2292)
            at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2386)
            at android.app.ActivityThread.access$900(ActivityThread.java:169)
            at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1277)
            at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102)
            at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:136)
            at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5476)
            at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
            at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:515)
            at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:1283)
            at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:1099)
            at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
 Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException
        at com.crifano.tatooPhoto.ui.MenuImages.a(Unknown Source)
        at com.crifano.tatooPhoto.ui.MenuImages.a(Unknown Source)
        at com.crifano.tatooPhoto.ui.MenuImages.onCreateView(Unknown Source)
        at android.app.Fragment.performCreateView(Fragment.java:1700)
        at android.app.FragmentManagerImpl.moveToState(FragmentManager.java:866)
        at android.app.FragmentManagerImpl.moveToState(FragmentManager.java:1040)
        at android.app.FragmentManagerImpl.addFragment(FragmentManager.java:1142)
        at android.app.Activity.onCreateView(Activity.java:4997)
        at android.view.LayoutInflater.createViewFromTag(LayoutInflater.java:695)
            at android.view.LayoutInflater.rInflate(LayoutInflater.java:761)
            at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:498)
            at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:398)
            at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:354)
            at com.android.internal.policy.impl.PhoneWindow.setContentView(PhoneWindow.java:366)
            at android.app.Activity.setContentView(Activity.java:2031)
            at com.crifano.tatooPhoto.ui.MainActivity.onCreate(Unknown Source)
            at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:5451)
            at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1093)
            at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2292)
            at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2386)
            at android.app.ActivityThread.access$900(ActivityThread.java:169)
            at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1277)
            at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102)
            at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:136)
            at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5476)
            at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
            at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:515)
            at     com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:1283)
            at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:1099)
            at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
```

After some search, the problem seems in my MenuImages class and I changed it from

```
 @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
                             Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        // Inflate the layout for this fragment
        view =  inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_menu_images, container, false);
    LinearLayout menu = (LinearLayout) view.findViewById(R.id.menu_images1);
    float scale = MainActivity.CONTEXT.getResources().getDisplayMetrics().density;
    pixelsSize = (int) (65 * scale + 0.5f);
    populateMenuAll(menu, "all", "false");

        return view ;
    }
```

to:

```
  @Override
        public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
                                 Bundle savedInstanceState) {
            // Inflate the layout for this fragment
            view =  inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_menu_images, container, false);
            return view ;
        }
    @Override
    public void onActivityCreated(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onActivityCreated(savedInstanceState);
        LinearLayout menu = (LinearLayout) view.findViewById(R.id.menu_images1);
        float scale = MainActivity.CONTEXT.getResources().getDisplayMetrics().density;
        pixelsSize = (int) (65 * scale + 0.5f);
        populateMenuAll(menu, "all", "false");

    }
```

After that I get an other error:
"Performing stop of activity that is not resumed:"
    and the app still not start (only on upgrade from previous version):

```
07-09 10:46:33.326  29119-29119/? E/ActivityThread﹕ Performing stop of activity that is not resumed: {com.sec.android.app.myfiles/com.sec.android.app.myfiles.MainActivity}
    java.lang.RuntimeException: Performing stop of activity that is not resumed: {com.sec.android.app.myfiles/com.sec.android.app.myfiles.MainActivity}
            at android.app.ActivityThread.performStopActivityInner(ActivityThread.java:3356)
            at android.app.ActivityThread.handleStopActivity(ActivityThread.java:3443)
            at android.app.ActivityThread.access$1200(ActivityThread.java:169)
            at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1304)
            at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102)
            at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:136)
            at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5476)
            at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
            at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:515)
            at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:1283)
            at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:1099)
            at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
07-09 10:46:34.536     781-1222/? E/EnterpriseContainerManager﹕ ContainerPolicy Service is not yet ready!!!
07-09 10:46:34.536     781-1222/? E/Parcel﹕ Class not found when unmarshalling: com.android.packageinstaller.InstallFlowAnalytics
    java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: com.android.packageinstaller.InstallFlowAnalytics
            at java.lang.Class.classForName(Native Method)
            at java.lang.Class.forName(Class.java:251)
            at java.lang.Class.forName(Class.java:216)
            at android.os.Parcel.readParcelableCreator(Parcel.java:2140)
            at android.os.Parcel.readParcelable(Parcel.java:2104)
            at android.os.Parcel.readValue(Parcel.java:2020)
            at android.os.Parcel.readArrayMapInternal(Parcel.java:2321)
            at android.os.Bundle.unparcel(Bundle.java:249)
            at android.os.Bundle.getString(Bundle.java:1118)
            at android.content.Intent.getStringExtra(Intent.java:5128)
            at com.android.server.am.ActivityStackSupervisor.startActivityLocked(ActivityStackSupervisor.java:1446)
            at com.android.server.am.ActivityStackSupervisor.startActivityMayWait(ActivityStackSupervisor.java:1041)
            at com.android.server.am.ActivityManagerService.startActivityAsUser(ActivityManagerService.java:4055)
            at com.android.server.am.ActivityManagerService.startActivity(ActivityManagerService.java:3949)
            at android.app.ActivityManagerNative.onTransact(ActivityManagerNative.java:159)
            at com.android.server.am.ActivityManagerService.onTransact(ActivityManagerService.java:2630)
            at android.os.Binder.execTransact(Binder.java:404)
            at dalvik.system.NativeStart.run(Native Method)
     Caused by: java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: com/android/packageinstaller/InstallFlowAnalytics
            at java.lang.Class.classForName(Native Method)
            at java.lang.Class.forName(Class.java:251)
            at java.lang.Class.forName(Class.java:216)
            at android.os.Parcel.readParcelableCreator(Parcel.java:2140)
            at android.os.Parcel.readParcelable(Parcel.java:2104)
            at android.os.Parcel.readValue(Parcel.java:2020)
            at android.os.Parcel.readArrayMapInternal(Parcel.java:2321)
            at android.os.Bundle.unparcel(Bundle.java:249)
            at android.os.Bundle.getString(Bundle.java:1118)
            at android.content.Intent.getStringExtra(Intent.java:5128)
            at com.android.server.am.ActivityStackSupervisor.startActivityLocked(ActivityStackSupervisor.java:1446)
            at com.android.server.am.ActivityStackSupervisor.startActivityMayWait(ActivityStackSupervisor.java:1041)
            at com.android.server.am.ActivityManagerService.startActivityAsUser(ActivityManagerService.java:4055)
            at com.android.server.am.ActivityManagerService.startActivity(ActivityManagerService.java:3949)
            at android.app.ActivityManagerNative.onTransact(ActivityManagerNative.java:159)
            at com.android.server.am.ActivityManagerService.onTransact(ActivityManagerService.java:2630)
            at android.os.Binder.execTransact(Binder.java:404)
            at dalvik.system.NativeStart.run(Native Method)
     Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: Didn't find class "com.android.packageinstaller.InstallFlowAnalytics" on path: DexPathList[[directory "."],nativeLibraryDirectories=[/vendor/lib, /system/lib]]
            at dalvik.system.BaseDexClassLoader.findClass(BaseDexClassLoader.java:67)
            at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:497)
            at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:457)
            at java.lang.Class.classForName(Native Method)
            at java.lang.Class.forName(Class.java:251)
            at java.lang.Class.forName(Class.java:216)
            at android.os.Parcel.readParcelableCreator(Parcel.java:2140)
            at android.os.Parcel.readParcelable(Parcel.java:2104)
            at android.os.Parcel.readValue(Parcel.java:2020)
            at android.os.Parcel.readArrayMapInternal(Parcel.java:2321)
            at android.os.Bundle.unparcel(Bundle.java:249)
            at android.os.Bundle.getString(Bundle.java:1118)
            at android.content.Intent.getStringExtra(Intent.java:5128)
            at com.android.server.am.ActivityStackSupervisor.startActivityLocked(ActivityStackSupervisor.java:1446)
            at com.android.server.am.ActivityStackSupervisor.startActivityMayWait(ActivityStackSupervisor.java:1041)
            at com.android.server.am.ActivityManagerService.startActivityAsUser(ActivityManagerService.java:4055)
            at com.android.server.am.ActivityManagerService.startActivity(ActivityManagerService.java:3949)
            at android.app.ActivityManagerNative.onTransact(ActivityManagerNative.java:159)
            at com.android.server.am.ActivityManagerService.onTransact(ActivityManagerService.java:2630)
            at android.os.Binder.execTransact(Binder.java:404)
            at dalvik.system.NativeStart.run(Native Method)
```

MainActivity is initialized like this:

```
public class MainActivity extends FragmentActivity implements
        MenuImages.OnFragmentInteractionListener{....}
```

MenuImages extends Fragment and in activity_main.xml I had

```
<fragment
    android:id="@+id/frg_images"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:name="com.crifano.tatooPhoto.ui.MenuImages"
    tools:layout="@layout/fragment_menu_images"
    android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
    android:layout_toEndOf="@+id/bt_categ"
    android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/bt_categ"
    />
```

The xml for MenuImage "fragment_menu_images.xml" is:

```
<FrameLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    tools:context="com.crifano.tatooPhoto.ui.MenuImages">

    <HorizontalScrollView
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"

        >
        <LinearLayout
            android:id="@+id/menu_images1"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:orientation="horizontal"
            android:background="#FFFFFF"
            android:scrollingCache="false"
            android:animationCache="false"
            android:smoothScrollbar="true"
            />
    </HorizontalScrollView>

</FrameLayout>
```

Could somebody help me please?
I use a galaxy S III with android 4.4.2 installed
Thanks

Comment: It's diffcult to debug better because I can only test it with a signed apk, as I have not the unsigned apk of previous version. And with signed apk I can only see the "error" log on my logcat

Comment: Sorry I solved my problem... and probably is nothing about the code I wrote upper ... The real problem was an implementation on internal DB... it causes the crash

Comment: Hi, can you elaborate on your solution? I have the same problem and I'm stuck on that one for almost two days now :D

Comment: @jdabrowski Did you ever find the solution?